# NullPointerException on save in DynamoDB

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb

I have a `User` entity with an `id`

```
@DynamoDBTable(tableName = "User")
public class User {
  ...
  @DynamoDBHashKey(attributeName = "id")
  @DynamoDBAutoGeneratedKey
  public String getId() {
    ...
  }
  // other attributes, getters and setters omitted for simplicity
  ...
}
```

and a `User` Table with key name `id` of type `S`

```
final ArrayList<KeySchemaElement> keySchema = new ArrayList<KeySchemaElement>();
keySchema.add(new KeySchemaElement().withAttributeName(pKeyName).withKeyType(KeyType.HASH));
final ArrayList<AttributeDefinition> attributeDefinitions = new ArrayList<AttributeDefinition>();
attributeDefinitions.add(new AttributeDefinition().withAttributeName(pKeyName).withAttributeType(pKeyType));
final CreateTableRequest request = new CreateTableRequest().withTableName(pTableName).withKeySchema(keySchema)
            .withProvisionedThroughput(new ProvisionedThroughput().withReadCapacityUnits(10L).withWriteCapacityUnits(5L));
request.setAttributeDefinitions(attributeDefinitions);
```

on doing a 'save' operation

```
public <S extends User> S save(final S pUser) {
    mapper.save(pUser);
    return pUser;
}
```

I get a NullPointerException from within the DBMapper code

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBMapper$SaveObjectHandler.doPutItem(DynamoDBMapper.java:883) ~[aws-java-sdk-dynamodb-1.11.295.jar!/:na]
...
at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.AbstractDynamoDBMapper.save(AbstractDynamoDBMapper.java:123) ~[aws-java-sdk-dynamodb-1.11.295.jar!/:na]
at hello.user.repository.UserRepository.save(UserRepository.java:85) ~[classes!/:0.1.0]
```

My user object is not `null`, nor are any of its attributes other than the `id` which is autogenerated. Any idea what's going on?

Is the null id causing the exception? Is this not how I should expect `@DynamoDBAutoGeneratedKey` to work? According to the documentation and example at
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBMapper.Annotations.html#DynamoDBMapper.Annotations.DynamoDBAutoGeneratedKey
this should be how it works

Comment: The "Update" invalidates everything above it.  Please rewrite the post to ask the ***real*** question.  You should probably delete it, then [edit] it and then undelete to avoid downvotes/close votes.

Comment: Do you have a setter for the `id`? Perhaps you need one?

Comment: @JimGarrison, have cleaned up the question. It still stands. There is a NullPointerException on save and the library, nor the documentation, is particularly helpful at indicating why.

Comment: @Rohan, I have a simple public setter for Id. I have omitted it from the question for simplicity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not because of a `null` attribute value.

The issue is one of timing, or rather, of sequencing. The NullPointerException occurs in `doPutItem(DynamoDBMapper.java:883)`. Looking at the source code, the line is

```
883    return db.putItem(applyUserAgent(req));
```

this implies that `db` is null.

`db` is a member variable

```
191    private final AmazonDynamoDB db;
```

and it is initialised in the constructor

```
public DynamoDBMapper(
        final AmazonDynamoDB dynamoDB,
        final DynamoDBMapperConfig config,
        final AttributeTransformer transformer,
        final AWSCredentialsProvider s3CredentialsProvider) {
    super(config);
    ...
    this.db = dynamoDB;
    ...
}
```

So, `db` is the instance of `AmazonDynamoDB` client that *you* pass when creating the mapper.

In a spring context, if the mapper is being constructed before the client has been provided an (`@Autowired`) value, then it will be null.

Ensure the right sequencing of creation of the `AmazonDynamoDB` client and the `DynamoDBMapper` and everything will be fine

Comment: In my case, `AmazonDynamoDB` and `DynamoDBMapper` instances are created as beans and mapper had been created before db instance is created. Adding `@DependsOn` to mapper bean creation solved the problem.